# Property 'commit' does not exist

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

When I use Vuex in JavaScript, it works well but after I want to change it to TypeScript, it tell me that `Property 'commit' does not exist` in Vuex's mutations:

```js
const mutations = {
  methodA (): none {
    this.commit('methodB') // raise error here!!! <- Property 'commit' does not exist on type '...'
  },
  methodB (): nont {
    log.console('hello')
  }
}
```

What should I do to let it works.

EDIT:

still waiting... www

EDIT:

Here is the part of the whole file, maybe it is too long(200 lines) for you:

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api'

import { remote } from 'electron'

// editor_text_C: const state for editor's text
const editor_text_C = {
  main: 'Text TODO, enter <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> to submit:',
  sub: title => `Text TODO, enter <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> for submit for ` +
                `${JSON.stringify(title)}, and enter <kbd>Esc</kbd> to ` +
                `leave:`
}

interface Bar {
  title: string;
  time: Date;
  OK: boolean;
  folding: boolean;
  child: Bar[];
}

interface Editor {
  text: string;
  index: number[];
  container?: HTMLElement;
  // TODO: ugly type
  obj: any;
}

interface State {
  bars: Bar[];
  editor: Editor;
  filePath: string;
}

const state = (): State => ({
  bars: [],
  editor: {
    text: editor_text_C.main,
    index: [],
    container: undefined,
    obj: null
  },
  filePath: ''
})

// make the bar/bars be normal, be in bars' shape
var normalBar = (bar: any): Bar => {
  if (!bar['title']) console.error('Bar require title')
  bar['time'] = bar['time'] ? new Date(bar['time']) : new Date()
  bar['OK'] = bar['OK'] ? bar['OK'] : false
  bar['folding'] = bar['folding'] ? bar['folding'] : false
  bar['child'] = normalBars(bar['child'])
  return bar
}

var normalBars = (bars: any[]): Bar[] => {
  var result = []
  if (bars) {
    for (var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
      if(bars[i])
        result.push(normalBar(bars[i]))
    }
  }
  return result
}

// get the bar by index
var barByIndex = (bars: Bar[], index: number[]): Bar => {
  var result: any = { child: bars }
  for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
    result = result.child[index[i]]
  }
  return result as Bar
}

// mutations
const mutations = {
  init (state: State, { filePath }: { filePath: string; }) {
    // init Bars for todo application.
    // read `json` file form filePath, then init state.bars with update mutations.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    state.filePath = filePath
    fs.readFile(state.filePath, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        this.update(state, {
          bars: normalBars([
            {title: '1. Click on my text to set my state (OK/Todo)'},
            {title: ['2. Want to set a new Todo? Edit at below editor, then press',
              ' `Ctrl+Enter`'].join('')},
            {title: ['3. A Useless Todo bar? move on me and you can find a bin ',
              'icon, then click on the my delete bin icon'].join('')}
          ])
        })
        return
      }
      state.bars = normalBars(JSON.parse(data.toString()))
    })

    // init the Editor
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    state.editor.container = document.createElement('div')
    state.editor.container.style.height = '5em'
    state.editor.obj = monaco.editor.create(state.editor.container, {
      value: '',
      language: 'markdown',
      folding: true,
      foldingStrategy: 'indentation',
      automaticLayout: true,
      overviewRulerBorder: false,
      scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
      minimap: {
        enabled: false
      }
    })
    // Set the command for edit to enter the message
    state.editor.obj.addCommand(monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.Enter, () => {
      this.commit('todolist/submit', { message: state.editor.obj.getValue() })
      state.editor.obj.setValue('')
    })
    // Set the command for enter the message for root
    state.editor.obj.addCommand(monaco.KeyCode.Escape, () => {
      this.commit('todolist/addBar', { index: undefined })
    })
  },

  // update Bars and save
  // set the state.bars' value to `bars`, then write it to filePath
  update (state: State, { bars }: { bars: Bar[]; }) {
    state.bars = bars
    fs.writeFile(state.filePath, JSON.stringify(state.bars), (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(`Cannot write to ${state.filePath}!`)
      }
    })
  },

  // kill bar by index
  killBar (state: State, { index }: { index: number[] }) {
    // reset the editor's index
    this.commit('todolist/addBar', { index: undefined })

    var index_ = index.slice()
    if (index.length != 1) {
      var i = index_.pop()
      var aim = barByIndex(state.bars, index_)
      remote.clipboard.writeText(aim.child[i].title)
      aim.child.splice(i, 1)
      this.commit('todolist/update', { bars: state.bars })
    } else {
      remote.clipboard.writeText(state.bars[index[0]].title)
      state.bars.splice(index[0], 1)
      this.commit('todolist/update', { bars: state.bars })
    }
  },

  // change the bay's OK state by index
  changeState (state: State, { index }: { index: number[] }) {
    var aim = barByIndex(state.bars, index)
    aim.OK = !aim.OK
    this.commit('todolist/update', { bars: state.bars })
  },

  // add Bar for todo list:
  //  - if index == undef, add bar to the root
  //  - else, add bar for bars[index[0]][index[1]]...
  addBar (state: State, { index }: { index: number[] }) {
    state.editor.index = index

    if (state.editor.index != undefined) {
      var aim = barByIndex(state.bars, state.editor.index)
      state.editor.text = editor_text_C.sub(aim.title)
    } else {
      state.editor.text = editor_text_C.main
    }

    // focus on the editor auto
    state.editor.obj.focus()
    this.commit('todolist/update', { bars: state.bars })
  },

  // fold Bar for todo list
  foldBar (state: State, { index }: { index: number[]; }) {
    var aim = barByIndex(state.bars, index)
    aim.folding = !aim.folding
    this.commit('todolist/update', { bars: state.bars })
  },

  // submit by message and index, and then update it:
  //  - if index == undef, add bar to the root
  //  - else, add bar for bars[index]
  submit (state: State, { message }: { message: string; }) {
    if (state.editor.index != undefined) {
      var aim = barByIndex(state.bars, state.editor.index)
      aim.child.unshift(normalBar({title: message}))
      this.commit('todolist/update', { bars: state.bars })
    } else {
      state.bars.unshift(normalBar({title: message}))
      this.commit('todolist/update', { bars: state.bars })
    }
  }
}

const getters = {
  state: (state: State) => (index: number[]) => {
    var aim = barByIndex(state.bars, index)
    if (aim.child.length != 0) {
      return aim.folding ? 'folding' : 'unfolding'
    } else {
      return aim.OK ? 'OK' : 'not OK'
    }
  },
  folding: (state: State) => (index: number[]) => {
    return barByIndex(state.bars, index).folding
  },
  havechildren: (state: State) => (index: number[]) => {
    return barByIndex(state.bars, index).child.length != 0
  },
  OK: (state: State, getters: any) => (index: number[]) => {
    var aim = barByIndex(state.bars, index)
    if (getters['havechildren'](index)) {
      var flag = true
      for (var i = 0; i < aim.child.length; i ++) {
        if (!getters['OK'](index.concat(i))) {
          flag = false
        }
      }
      return flag
    } else {
      return aim.OK
    }
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  getters
}
```

Here is some informations maybe help or not: It is build with `electron`, and I am going to make it into typescript file, and it is a Vue store file under path `./src/store/modules/todolist.vue`.

Comment: Are you using a simple vue SPA or something with nuxt? Show your whole file please

Comment: @DarioRega hello? I add the whole file, which is for vue SPA application.

Comment: Well sorry but i don't know electron and im not a big guy of typescript, can't help ya sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you should never commit a mutation from inside another mutation in vuex. A mutation should only make immediate changes to the state, and this is designed like that to keep better chronological track of atomic changes to the state.

If you want to wrap logic around calls to mutations you should use an action instead.
Actions receive a context object with the 'commit' method inside.

So, in your simple example you could make an action that secuentially commits 'methodA' and then 'methodB'.

```
const actions = {
  actionOne ({commit}): none {
    commit('methodA')
    commit('methodB')
  },
}
```

If you have any additional logic (ie. conditionally commiting one or another mutation) you can put it there inside your action.